# is it possible to let spark structured stream(update mode) to write to db?

Tags: apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-structured-streaming

I use spark(3.0.0) structured streaming to read topic from kafka.

I've used `joins` and then used `mapGropusWithState` to get my stream data, so I **have to** use **update** mode, based on my understanding from the spark offical guide: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-modes

Below section of the spark offical guide says nothing about `DB sink`, and It does not support write to `files` either for `update mode`: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks

Currently I output it to `console`, and I would like to to store the data in files or DB.

So my **question** is:
how can I write the stream data to db or file in my situation?
Do i have to write the data to kafka and then use kafka connect to read them back to files/db?

p.s. I followed the articles to get the `aggregated` streaming query.

```
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62738727/how-to-deduplicate-and-keep-latest-based-on-timestamp-field-in-spark-structured
- https://databricks.com/blog/2017/10/17/arbitrary-stateful-processing-in-apache-sparks-structured-streaming.html
- will also try one more time for below using java api
(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50933606/spark-streaming-select-record-with-max-timestamp-for-each-id-in-dataframe-pysp)
```

Comment: Cant you use JDBC to write to DB. jdbcDF.write
  .format("jdbc")
  .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql:dbserver")
  .option("dbtable", "schema.tablename")
  .option("user", "username")
  .option("password", "password")
  .save()

Comment: what is database flavor?

Comment: @Alex Ott, can be in memory one -H2

Answer (score 0):

I got confused by the OUTPUT and WRITE. Also I was wrongly assuming the DB and FILE Sink are in parallel term in the OUTPUT SINK section of the doc(and so one cannot see DB sink in the OUTPUT SINKs section of the guide: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#output-sinks).

I just realized that the OUTPUT mode (append/update/complete) is to do query streaming query constraints. But it has nothing to do with how to WRITE to the SINK. I also realized the DB writing can be achieved by using the FOREACH SINK (initially I just understood it is for extra transformation).

**I found these articles/discussions are useful**

- https://www.waitingforcode.com/apache-spark-structured-streaming/output-modes-structured-streaming/read#what_is_the_difference_with_SaveMode
- [How to write streaming dataframe to PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54756840/how-to-write-streaming-dataframe-to-postgresql)
- https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-list-databases-tables-in-postgreqsl/

so later on, read the official guide again, confirmed the for each batch can also do custom logic etc when WRITING to a STORAGE.

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch

Comment: found still have problems with possible UPDATE ouptput mode. wrote question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63981488/mapgroupswithstate-spark-sql-return-empty-dataset-at-the-start where i have to use UPDATE mode due to mapGroupsWithState function usage.